# How to properly add OAuth headers for a QuickBooks API call in Google Go

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, go, quickbooks-online

I am just trying to get a proof of concept working to test a connection to the QB api for a QB Online account.  I have never tried to make an OAuth connection before like this, so I'm not sure that I am doing it right.  Here's what I have so far, and it makes the request but I get a 401 error returned from QB's server (Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid401SERVER):

```
client := &http.Client{}
if req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/resource/customers/v2/717594130", nil); err != nil {
    //handle error
} else {
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_token=\"MY_TOKEN\",oauth_nonce=\"7758caa9-e1f4-4fa1-84c5-5759fd513a88\",oauth_consumer_key=\"MY_KEY\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1369259523\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"MY_SIG\"")
    if resp, err := client.Do(req); err != nil {
        //handle error
    } else {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            //handle error
        }
        myOutput := string(contents)
    }
}
```

Could the problem may be with my settings on my QB account instead?  There is a setting for "Host Name Domain" that I think it might only allow connections from what I have entered there (which is currently intuit.com).  If that is the case, how do I set that to allow connections from my dev app on my localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the correct OAuth algorithm to generate the signature?

Can you post an actual request/response that shows the outgoing signature/OAuth header, and the response you get back from Intuit?

Your code doesn't show any of that, and it doesn't look like you're using an Intuit DevKit, so that's probably the place to start. My guess would be that the signature you're sending isn't valid. I would *highly* recommend you find a OAuth library, and use that OAuth library, rather than try to roll your own OAuth algorithm.

As far as this goes:

> Could the problem may be with my settings on my QB account instead?
>   There is a setting for "Host Name Domain" that I think it might only
>   allow connections from what I have entered there (which is currently
>   intuit.com).

That is *not* likely to be the problem... but to get any further than a simple test request, you *will* need to set that to your host name. If it's a local dev box, you can enter your local dev boxes hostname (e.g. `http://localhost/` or `http://192.168.1.2/` or anything like that is fine - whatever URL you use to hit your dev box)

Comment: For development boxes without a "real" hostname or internet access I often use http://pagekite.net to get a proper externally accessible hostname.

Comment: PageKite.net is a good solution if you need an externally accessible hostname. Note, though, that for this particular OAuth situation, you do *not* need an externally accessible hostname.

Comment: Thank you, Keith, after posting the question I did find an appropriate OAth library written for Go which I am trying to use now.  Still having problems there, but that's another story.  I am new to OAuth, and my original question already seems naive, oh well.  Thanks for your help.